# defining new variable within jquery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Is it possible to define a new variable within a jquery template?
I read the official jquery template docs but could not find anything on this.
I tried something like `{{ var xxx=123 }}` but it didn't work.
Finally I am using a hack by doing

`${$item.xxx=123,""}`

and later using

`$item.xxx`

but I am sure it is not the best approach...

Comment: Your question was a good answer :)

Answer (score 21):

I don't think that doing the $item approach is too bad.  It is consistent with where you would look for variables that are passed in via the options parameter to $.tmpl.

Another approach that I have used, based on a small tip [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/variable-support-in-jquery-templates), is to actually define a "var" template tag.

Just do:

```
$.extend($.tmpl.tag, {
    "var": {
        open: "var $1;"
    }
});
```

Then you can use it in your templates like:

```
{{var xxx=123}}
...
<div>${xxx}</div>
```

Also, nice blog post here on custom jquery template tags: http://blog.sterkwebwerk.nl/2010/12/15/custom-jquery-template-tags-1/

Comment: And for setting variables perhaps `$.extend($.tmpl.tag, {"setvar": {open: "$1;"}});`

Answer (score 2):

You can extend jquery template with eval tag

```
$.extend($.tmpl.tag, { "eval": { open: "$1;"} });
```

and use

```
{{eval var xxx = 123}}
{{eval xxx += 23}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do:

```
${xxx=13, ""}
```

and then i can use xxx in a sub or in the same template

Comment: jquery.tmpl creates these variables in global context. `xxx` will be global variable.